# ReactJS - PropTypes not validating

Tags: reactjs

`PropTypes` is not validationg (ignore!!!) this simple component, I tried everything but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import Item from "./Item";

import chunkArray from "../../utils/chunkArray";


const AllItems = (props) => {
  const { items, title } = props;

  const [arrayToMap, setArrayToMap] = useState([]);

  // set size array based on columns
  const arrSize = 12;

  // chunk array
  useEffect(() => {
    setArrayToMap(chunkArray(items, arrSize));
  }, [items]);


  return (
    <>
      {arrayToMap.length === 0 ? (
        <div>Wait</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          {title}
          {arrayToMap.map((x) => {
            return (
              <div className="row">
                {x.map((y, i) => (
                  <div className="col-1" key={i}>
                    <Item item={y} size={"small"} />
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

AllItems.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};


export default AllItems;
```

I can pass whatever to `ìtems` or `title` but doesn't stop the render.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: open the console. Proptypes doesn't stop the component from rendering.

Comment: Yes, but it does not give eany warning/error. ?

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

rerendering your component is not about proptypes, it's because you set state in your useEffect function without any condition. so the component will work in an infinite loop of rendering. you can read about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do)

you need to add some condition to set your state in once like this :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(arrayToMap.length === 0 && items.length > 0){
      setArrayToMap(chunkArray(items, arrSize));
    }
  }, [items]);
```

so if your state is clear and your `items` array is not empty so the condition will work.

Comment: Thansk for the answer but it does not change. I would like to use ProtoTypes to stop the rendering once a wrong value is provided. i.e. a `string` instead of an `array`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing the warnings, Is because you're using props as the param in your component. Change your component to the following

```
const AllItems = ({ items, title }) => {}
```

Proptypes doesn't stop component from rendering but you can use eslint to validate the params and stop the app from starting. Add eslintrc.json file to your project and add the following rule.

```
"react/prop-types": 2,
```

Comment: This still does not stop the app from running. and also the components that don't have PropTypes validation, their props are marked as error in the editor.